# How to remove HTML tags as well as HTML content within a string in PHP?

Tags: php, html, laravel, string

I have a .txt file. Using the following code I read it:

```
while (!feof($handle)) {
            yield trim(utf8_encode(fgets($handle)));
        }
```

Now from the retrieved string I want to remove not only the HTML tags but also the HTML content inside. Found many solutions to remove the tags but not both - tags + content.

Sample string - `Hey my name is <b>John</b>. I am a <i>coder</i>!`

Required output string - `Hey my name is . I am a !`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Is the string of yours is coming from a variable passed to the blade.php? if yes, display the string in curly braces followed by exclamatory mark `{!! $string !!}`

Comment: Actually, the string is inside a .txt file.

Comment: Add the code how you display the .txt content in the question as well, which will make it easier for users to answer your query

Comment: Added code how I read the .txt file

Comment: @TejasS How about regex /(<([^>]+)>).*?(<\/\2>)/

Comment: @NgoTuan Unwritten rule of parsing HTML: Don't use RegEx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to achieve this is by using `DOMDocument` and `DOMXPath`. My solution assumes that the provided HTML string has no container node or that the container node contents are not meant to be stripped (as this would result in a completely empty string).

```php
$string = 'Hey my name is <b>John</b>. I am a <i>coder</i>!';

// create a DOMDocument (an XML/HTML parser)
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
// load the HTML string without adding a <!DOCTYPE ...> and <html><body> tags
// and with error/warning reports turned off
// if loading fails, there's something seriously wrong with the HTML
if($dom->loadHTML($string, LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD | LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING)) {
  // create an DOMXPath instance for the loaded document
  $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

  // remember the root node; DOMDocument automatically adds a <p> container if one is not present
  $rootNode = $dom->documentElement;
  // fetch all descendant nodes (children and grandchildren, etc.) of the root node
  $childNodes = $xpath->query('//*', $rootNode);
  // with each of these decendants...
  foreach($childNodes as $childNode) {
    // ...remove them from their parent node
    $childNode->parentNode->removeChild($childNode);
  }

  // echo the sanitized HTML
  echo $rootNode->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

---

If you *do* want to strip a potential container code then it's going to be a bit harder, because it's difficult to differentiate between an original container node and a container node that's automatically added by `DOMDocument`.

---

Also, if an unintended non-closing tag is found, it can lead to unexpected results, as it will strip everything until the next closing tag, because `DOMDocument` will automatically add a closing tag for invalid non-closing tags.

Comment: It worked. Thank you!